# Locating the terminal currently in use

Tags: terminal, scripting, tty, csh

I need to write a script to test if I'm using the correct terminal and then print a message.
This is what I have so far:

```csh
if(???? == dev/pts/1)
  echo Access Granted. Welcome.
endif
```

I don't know how to use tty to find the terminal though. 
Using csh.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In bash you can test as follows:

```
[[ `tty` = "/dev/pts/1" ]] && echo Access Granted. Welcome.
```

`tty` will generally output something like `/dev/pts/1` or `not a tty`

As you mentioned, apparently in csh you can do as follows:

```
if ($tty == "pts/1") then
    echo Access Granted. Welcome.
endif
```

Comment: i got it working using $tty in my condition and I needed to add a "then" after the if statement and condition